# How to ignore loss only some of the time in PyTorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

While training a neural net in PyTorch, I'd like to be able to look at the model outputs and decide whether a particular output should result in a loss or just be ignored (=zero loss).

The usual training loop looks something like this:

```
for (data, labels) in loader:
    data, labels = data.to(device), labels.to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    logits = model(data)
    loss = criterion(logits, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

What is the best way to zero out some of the losses?

Should I make some of the labels equal to the logits before calculating criterion?

Or, can I modify the loss after calculating it before calling loss.backward()? (and how? I could multiply it by a mask of zeros and ones, or round-trip it to a numpy array and modify it, etc)

The use case here is semantic segmentation, *sort of*.  The labels are a coarse image, where each region (corresponding to a 32x32 patch in the input image) can be either "yes", "no", or "ambiguous".  The "ambiguous" ones should not produce a loss, whatever the network output is.  In this case I know which losses should be ignored right up front, from the labels; but I'd like to also know how to ignore based on the outputs as well as the labels.

Comment: Making the loss zero won't make the gradients zero if that's what you want i.e. for the model to not get updated. If you want the model to not be updated in certain cases, then you could put an if condition for it and put the `optimizer.step()` within the condition.

Comment: @akshayk07 Thanks, that's helpful; I figured it wouldn't be as simple as setting the loss to zero.  I need some parts of the minibatch - or some parts of the labels - to not contribute to the gradient; not to skip the update completely for that minibatch.

Answer (score -2):

While training the network, you can save the best model if validation loss as decreased.
Try this code:

```
if valid_loss <= valid_loss_min:
        print('Validation loss decreased ({:.6f} --> {:.6f}).  Saving model ...'.format(valid_loss_min, valid_loss))
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_name.pt')
        valid_loss_min = valid_loss
```

Comment: Thank you, that's not what I'm looking for.  I need to disable/zero out the gradients produced by some parts of the loss, not to save the best model.